# Loop through all matrices

Tags: loops, matrix, sage

How do I loop through all nxn matrices of a finite field like Z/pZ in sage?

Do I have to build up n² iterated loops or is there a better way? I'd like to let n flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MatrixSpace` type is what you want.

```
M = MatrixSpace(GF(5),2,2)
M.list()
```

Don't try this at home with large numbers!

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me why
space = MatrixSpace(GF(5),3,3)
print len(space.list())
takes forever?

Comment: I see, 1.953.125 is already too big for sage. Didn't expect that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "too big" but yes some data structures might be too big.    I think that there should be other methods available to `space` to find the cardinality - or in your case, just print `5^9`.   I'm not sure whether that would be a hard limit, it could have something to do with where you are doing it, timeout settings if you are in a notebook, etc.